# What is the easiest way to compare two web pages using python?

Tags: python, comparison, nlp

Hello I want to Compare two webpages using python script.
how can i achieve it? thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you want to compare? Do you just want to know whether they are exactly the same? Or whether they look the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you want to retrieve both webpages. You can use wget, urlretrieve, etc.:
[wget Vs urlretrieve of python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974741/wget-vs-urlretrieve-of-python)

Second, you want to "compare" the pages.  You can use a "diff" tool as Chinmay noted.  You can also do a keyword analysis of the two pages:

1. Parse all keywords from page. e.g.  [How do I extract keywords used in text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575246/how-do-i-extract-keywords-used-in-text)
2. Optionally take the "stem" of the words with something like:
   http://pypi.python.org/pypi/stemming/1.0
3. Use some math to compare the two pages' keywords, e.g. term frequency–inverse document frequency: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf with some of the python tools out there like these: http://wiki.python.org/moin/InformationRetrieval

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by compare? If you just want to find the differences between two files, try [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html), which is part of the standard Python library.