# Download all the links(related documents) on a webpage using Python

Tags: python

I have to download a lot of documents from a webpage. They are wmv files, PDF, BMP etc. Of course, all of them have links to them. So each time, I have to RMC a file, select 'Save Link As' Then save then as type All Files. Is it possible to do this in Python? I search the SO DB and folks have answered question of how to get the links from the webpage. I want to download the actual files. Thanks in advance. (This is not a HW question :)).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is an example of how you could download some chosen files from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt

you will need to install mechanize first: http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/download.html

```
import mechanize
from time import sleep
#Make a Browser (think of this as chrome or firefox etc)
br = mechanize.Browser()

#visit http://stockrt.github.com/p/emulating-a-browser-in-python-with-mechanize/
#for more ways to set up your br browser object e.g. so it look like mozilla
#and if you need to fill out forms with passwords.

# Open your site
br.open('http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt')

f=open("source.html","w")
f.write(br.response().read()) #can be helpful for debugging maybe

filetypes=[".zip",".exe",".tar.gz"] #you will need to do some kind of pattern matching on your files
myfiles=[]
for l in br.links(): #you can also iterate through br.forms() to print forms on the page!
    for t in filetypes:
        if t in str(l): #check if this link has the file extension we want (you may choose to use reg expressions or something)
            myfiles.append(l)


def downloadlink(l):
    f=open(l.text,"w") #perhaps you should open in a better way & ensure that file doesn't already exist.
    br.click_link(l)
    f.write(br.response().read())
    print l.text," has been downloaded"
    #br.back()

for l in myfiles:
    sleep(1) #throttle so you dont hammer the site
    downloadlink(l)
```

Note: In some cases you may wish to replace `br.click_link(l)` with `br.follow_link(l)`. The difference is that click_link returns a Request object whereas follow_link will directly open the link. See [Mechanize difference between br.click_link() and br.follow_link()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204781/mechanize-difference-between-br-click-link-and-br-follow-link)

Comment: robert kink, i run your code for only download zip files- the code run with no errors but in the chrom download folder i don't see the files

Comment: hmm i think the file will get downloaded to the folder that you ran the python script from. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory

Comment: people could also consider pupeteer?
https://pypi.org/project/pyppeteer/

Comment: @newGIS I faced the same problem. Replacing br.click_link(l) with the following statement worked for me: 
br.retrieve(str(l.url), f'{l.text}.mp3')[0]

Answer (score 6):

- Follow the Python codes in this link: [wget-vs-urlretrieve-of-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974741/wget-vs-urlretrieve-of-python).
- You can also do this very easily with [Wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html). Try `--limit`, `--recursive` and `--accept` command-lines in `Wget`. For example:
  `wget --accept wmv,doc --limit 2 --recursive http://www.example.com/files/`