# Is there a python module which web scrapes the image, title and a description of any link?

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup, web-scraping

What I'm looking for, should give me something like this ->
[image]

Comment: No. Do it yourself. You can see as well as anyone else what the HTML is and so you can scrape it (read the Beautiful Soup documentation if you're not familiar with it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many APIs available that can accomplish your task (more precisely the task you describe on your question, not the image :) ). I personally use [diffbot](http://www.diffbot.com/), which I discovered after reading [this](http://www.readwriteweb.com/hack/2011/06/head-to-head-comparison-of-tex.php#.TfMwNJgETxs;hackernews). Beware though, for this kind of "content" extraction does not always end with success, because of the nature of web pages. Instead, it relies on heuristics and training and thus may not suffice for your specific purposes...

Comment: I think you just saved my life... : ]

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting an entire screenshot of the page then something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041371/alexa-api may help you?

Otherwise if you're just wanting to get a few key images from the page..

you could use mechanize to assit you. When you connect to a webpage you can search through all the links on the page using:

```
for link in br.links():
```

where br is your browser object.

You can see an example here:
[Download all the links(related documents) on a webpage using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974595/download-all-the-linksrelated-documents-on-a-webpage-using-python/5976423#5976423)

if you print dir(link) it will show you various properties such as link.text and link.url. furthermore you can import urlparse.urlsplit and use it on the url. You can direct the browser towards the URL and scrape the images as shown in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

You should really use a search engines interpretation of the page and the images in it.

You could use, the [python wrapper on the bing API](http://agiliq.com/blog/2009/06/python-wrapper-on-bing-api/), or the [xGoogle library](https://github.com/pkrumins/xgoogle).

Beware the xGoogle library fakes to google as if a browser and may not be endorsed way to consume Google's data.

Answer (score -1):

This one should help: http://palewi.re/posts/2008/04/20/python-recipe-grab-a-page-scrape-a-table-download-a-file/

Learns you how to scrape content and images and store it.